# Parsing request data Cloud Functions TypeScript + Android

Tags: android, typescript, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently trying to send data from an app to Firebase Cloud Functions.
This is my code in Android:

```
    val hashMap = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
    hashMap.put("uid", uid)
    val result = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
        .getHttpsCallable("getUserDetails")
        .call(hashMap).await()
```

And this is my TypeScript code:

```
export const getUserDetails = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
        try {
            console.log("uid" + request.rawBody + request.body.toString() + request.query.data
          + request.params.data)
..........................
}
```

I tried request.param("","") is deprecated.
I tried with request.params.uid and I tried parsing with JSON but nothing is working.
In the log I can see that request.rawBody has the data but I don't know how to get to the specific field I want

[image: Log Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and [HTTP Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

You Cloud Function code corresponds to an HTTP one (`functions.https.onRequest(...)`) but the code in your front-end calls a Callable one (`FirebaseFunctions.getInstance().getHttpsCallable("getUserDetails")`).

You should adapt one or the other, most probably adapt your Cloud Function to a Callable one, along the following lines:

```
export const getUserDetails = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

        try {
             const uid = data.uid;

        // ..........................
}
```